# What is a nongeodesic orbit?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, acceleration

I have read that in the Schwarzschild spacetime for a nongeodesic circular orbit the radial acceleration becomes *positive* for $r<3r_S$. Intuitively, the acceleration should be negative, pulling the object in.

My questions:

1. What does a nongeodesic orbit even mean? Is it a solution to the general equation 
   $$f^\mu=ma^\mu$$
   where $a^\mu=u^\nu\nabla_\nu u^\mu$ is the proper acceleration? What is $f^\mu$ in this case?
2. Does this result make sense? If so, how? Why does the central mass seem to repel satellites?
3. If the equation in 1. is correct, then why does this behave differently than the geodesic case? I don't see how a term on the other side could change the behavior of the orbit this much.

Comment: Not sure about this, so posting as a comment. 1) As you imply, non-geodesic means that there is a force being applied - for example a rocket. This is the source of $f$. 2) Be careful with the term "radial" as we near $r_S$, as interpreting $r$ as the radius is no longer simple.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.2488v1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider a circular orbit in Schwarzschild coordinates, taken to be in the equatorial plane for simplicity. The test particle's position has components $x^\mu = (t, r, \pi/2, \phi)$, where $t$ and $\phi$ vary linearly with time/proper time and $r$ is constant. Then the $4$-velocity is $u^\mu = (\dot{t}, 0, 0, \dot{\phi})$, where dots denote derivatives with respect to the particle's proper time.

The proper acceleration has radial component
$$ a^r = \left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right) \left(\frac{M}{r^2} \dot{t}^2 - r \dot{\phi}^2\right), $$
as you are encouraged to check by crunching connection coefficients, either in the above equation or in the inhomogeneous geodesic equation (that is, where the right-hand-side is $a^\mu$ rather than $0$ but where $\ddot{r} = 0$). This holds for any circular (and equatorial) orbit, geodesic or not. **The orbit will be geodesic if and only if $a^r$ vanishes** (we can ignore the other components because we are already assuming uniform circular motion). A nongeodesic orbit will be going at the wrong velocity for its radius, and this situation will be maintained by an applied external acceleration $a^r$.

Now let's look at allowed angular velocities. Any massive particle should have a velocity (and therefore angular velocity) bound by a photon moving in the same (i.e. purely azimuthal) spatial direction. A circular, equatorial, null orbit will obey
$$ 0 = g_{\mu\nu} u_\mathrm{null}^\mu u_\mathrm{null}^\nu = -\left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right) \dot{t}_\mathrm{null}^2 + r^2 \dot{\phi}_\mathrm{null}^2, $$
where here dots refer to derivatives with respect to some affine parameter. This gives the bound on angular frequencies:
$$ \omega_\mathrm{max}^2 \equiv \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi_\mathrm{null}}{\mathrm{d}t_\mathrm{null}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{r^2} \left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right). $$

For massive objects, angular frequency $\omega \equiv \mathrm{d}\phi/\mathrm{d}t$ is bounded by $0 \leq \omega^2 < \omega_\mathrm{max}^2$. Rewriting our formula for radial acceleration, we have
$$ a^r = \left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right) \left(\frac{M}{r^2} - r\omega^2\right) \dot{t}^2. $$
Taking into account the positivity of the first term (since we are outside the horizon) and the particle's motion through time, we have
$$ a^r > \left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right) \left(\frac{M}{r^2} - r\omega_\mathrm{max}^2\right) \dot{t}^2 = \frac{1}{r^2} \left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right) (3M - r) \dot{t}^2. $$
For $2M < r < 3M$, $a^r$ must be strictly positive in order to maintain a circular orbit.

Note **it isn't the central mass that is providing the repelling force**. The idea is that within $3/2$ Schwarzschild radii of an object, there are no geodesic circular orbits. You can move in a circle, but you need a continuous source of outward acceleration to do so. Outside $r = 3M$, you can have geodesic orbits ($a^r = 0$), too-slow orbits ($a^r > 0$), or too-fast orbits ($a^r < 0$).

Comment: Excellent post, thank you. You even got me to calculate the proper acceleration.